# Java 303 / 349 start date before end date validation

Tags: java, validation, bean-validation

Is there a better way of writing a Java validator which ensures that a start date is before an end date than writing a class level ConstraintValidator in the  following manner:

```
// VALIDATOR IMPLEMENTATION

    public class StartBeforeEndDateValidator implements ConstraintValidator<StartBeforeEndDateValid, Object> {

        // cannot use LocalDate here...
        private String start;
        private String end;

        @Override
        public void initialize(final StartBeforeEndDateValid annotation) {
            start = annotation.start();
            end = annotation.end();

        }

        @Override
        public boolean isValid(final Object bean, final ConstraintValidatorContext context) {
            try {
                final String startDateStr = BeanUtils.getProperty(bean, start);
                final String endDateStr = BeanUtils.getProperty(bean, end);

                final LocalDate startDate = new LocalDate(startDateStr);
                final LocalDate endDate = new LocalDate(endDateStr);

                return !startDate.isAfter(endDate);
            } catch (final Exception e) {
                return false;
            }
        }
    }


// USAGE
    @StartBeforeEndDateValid(start = "startDate", end = "endDate")
    @Entity
    public class MyBean {

        @NotNull
        @Type(type = "org.jadira.usertype.dateandtime.joda.PersistentLocalDate")
        private LocalDate startDate;

        @Type(type = "org.jadira.usertype.dateandtime.joda.PersistentLocalDate")
        private LocalDate endDate;

        ... 
    }
```

I don't really like the fact that I have to use reflection to extract the 2 date objects from the bean. Unfortunately afaik the validation spec does not specify a way to set only the values you want to validate from the bean.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way would be to add an interface to `MyBean`

```
public interface StartEndDateable {
   public LocalDate getStartDate();
   public LocalDate getEndDate();
}

public class MyBean implements StartEndDatable {
...
```

Then you can set the generic type on `ConstraintValidator` to the new interface instead of Object.

```
public class StartBeforeEndDateValidator implements ConstraintValidator<StartBeforeEndDateValid, StartEndDatable> {

    @Override
    public void initialize(StartBeforeEndDateValid annotation) {
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isValid(StartEndDatable bean, ConstraintValidatorContext context) {
        final LocalDate startDate = bean.getStartDate();
        final LocalDate endDate = bean.getEndDate();

        return !startDate.isAfter(endDate);
    }
}
```

Obviously any class you then want to validate with the start and end date will have to implement the `StartEndDateable` (Not the best name, I know, but I'm sure you can think of something better) and define the `getStartDate` and `getEndDate` methods.

Comment: Hi George, I had considered adding a StartEndValidatable interface but again it doesn't seem the cleanest option - what if I had lots of cross parameter validation to do, I'd end up implementing tens of different interfaces just for validation and they'd pollute the essence of what my bean was actually trying to do. I was hoping more for something along the lines of being able to pass the 2 dates into the isValid method, but I don't think this is possible given the current spec. If I don't receive anything along these lines, I'll accept your answer as the best alternative. Thanks.

Comment: Another alternative would be to use a factory that creates a `MyBeanStartEndValidatable` that wraps around the `MyBean` so that you don't touch the implementation of `MyBean`. It does mean that you will have a lot individual classes for each of the different interfaces, but I think it a small price to pay. Personally I would go with explicit typing rather than use reflection because any later refactoring will be a bit of nighmare, break your code and be a bit of a headache to hunt down and fix.

Comment: You can always write a specific ConstraintValidator for MyBean. If you need StartBeforeEndDateValid only for a small number of objects this is probably easiest and avoids reflection. If you after a generic solution, you will need to use reflection. An alternative could be the Hibernate Validator specific @ScriptAssert.

Comment: Hi Hardy, the StartBeforeEndDate validator needs to be generic as we have a number of entities where this is required. I don't really want to drop into JavaScript using the @ScriptAssert tag as I've already got this which I prefer on a per-bean basis: 

`@AssertTrue(message = "start must be before end")
public boolean isDatesValid() {
  return !startDate.isAfter(endDate);
}`

I'm going to accept George's answer regarding an Interface as I think it's the best current solution for now. Thanks to you both.